# Наследование экземпляров класса в Python

Tags: python, ооп, наследование

Чувствую себя невероятно тупым... Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Хочу постичь ООП (желательно по Python'овски)
Мне надо (просто ради опыта в ООП) реализовать в виде классов и зависимостей между ними структуру в виде обратного дерева, вроде такой:

```
Альбом
Страница-1, Страница-2, Страница-3
Рисунок-1-1, Рисунок-1-2, Рисунок-2-1, Рисунок-3-1
```

то есть в которой каждый объект, кроме объекта Рисунок, является списком, который включает в себя нижестоящие по иерархии объекты.
Ну и надо предусмотреть методы:

- Получить все страницы альбома
- Получить все рисунки страницы
- Рисунку на 3 странице 1-го альбома подрисовать рога
- Скопировать рисунки из одного альбома в другой

Проблема в том, что я видимо не понимаю какой-то очевидной сути ООП.
Под наследованием в ООП ведь понимается наследование дочерним классом методов и атрибутов родительского класса. А у меня у рисунка метод "Подрисовать", у страницы метод "Получить все рисунки", а у альбома "Получить все страницы" и "Скопировать все рисунки со всех страниц".

Не понимаю как эту задачу в парадигме ООП решить :(( А с помощью простых списков и функций за 5 минут накидаю

Comment: Создайте классы Альбома, Страницы и Рисунка. Добавьте им поля и методы, которые к ним относятся, например у Альбома есть список страниц и метод для их добавления, получения и т.п. И так для всех классов. Я, кст, подобное делал для формата fb2 -- там куча классов получилась: https://github.com/gil9red/pyfb2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По моему мнению вы свою задачу искусственно натягивается на ООП. У вас получается есть один объект со свойствами и всё. Создаём один класс и внутри всё делается "списками". Почитайте про ООП, проникнитесь наследованием, абстрагированием, полиморфизмом и пр. потенциалом этой парадигмы программирования.
В вашем примере как таковому наследования нет места. Должны были быть например разные страницы, на которых могли быть картинки и могли не быть. Можно было создать один класс страница и от него наследовать "с картинками"  и "без".

По вашем примеру, создадим класс страниц и рисунка, их можно не создавать, по причине указанной мной выше, но создадим:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.images = []
    def add_image(self, image):
        self.images.append(image)

class Image:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Далее главный класс со всеми функциями:

```
class Albom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pages = []
    def add_page(self, page):
        self.pages.append(page)
    def print_pages(self):
        print [tt.number for tt in self.pages]
    def print_image_from_page(self, page):
        for p in self.pages:
            if p.number == page:
                print [pp.name for pp in p.images]
    def draw_horns(self, page, image_name):
        for p in self.pages:
            if p.number == page:
                for n in p.images:
                    if n.name == image_name:
                        n.name = n.name + "_with_horns"
```

Теперь создадим экземпляры, добавим страниц, картинок и по-дёргаем методы:

```
a = Albom()
data = {1: ["cat", "dog"], 2: ["sky"], 3: ["sea", "island"]}
for h in data:
    b = Page(h)
    for d in data[h]:
        c = Image(d)
        b.add_image(c)
    a.add_page(b)

a.print_pages()
a.print_image_from_page(1)
a.draw_horns(1, "dog")
a.print_image_from_page(1)

# [1, 2, 3]
# ['cat', 'dog']
# ['cat', 'dog_with_horns']
```